# Library GD issue

Tags: php, composer-php, maatwebsite-excel

While installing maatwebsite/excel composer it is throwing an error regarding gd library is missing. But I checked in my system gd is already enabled.

Please see the error message below. I also attached a screenshot for the error and phpinfo screen.

Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

Problem 1

- Installation request for phpoffice/phpspreadsheet 1.14.1 -> satisfiable by phpoffice/phpspreadsheet[1.14.1].
- phpoffice/phpspreadsheet 1.14.1 requires ext-gd * -> the requested PHP extension gd is missing from your system.

*Problem 2*

- phpoffice/phpspreadsheet 1.14.1 requires ext-gd * -> the requested PHP extension gd is missing from your system.
- maatwebsite/excel 3.1.21 requires phpoffice/phpspreadsheet ^1.14 -> satisfiable by phpoffice/phpspreadsheet[1.14.1].
- Installation request for maatwebsite/excel 3.1.21 -> satisfiable by maatwebsite/excel[3.1.21].

To enable extensions, verify that they are enabled in your .ini files:

```
- /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-ext-intl.ini
- /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-ext-sodium.ini
- /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-ext-xdebug.ini
- /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-ext-zip.ini
```

You can also run `php --ini` inside terminal to see which files are used by PHP in CLI mode.

[image]

Comment: How did you ensure that GD is **really** enabled? If this was the case, Composer would not complain

Comment: I checked into the php.ini. Also when run phpinfo it shows gd is enabled. I don't know why composer throwing gd is missing in the system.

Comment: Have you checked whether GD is also enabled for the CLI version of PHP? According to that list of extensions, that might not be the case, so **how** did you check that?

Comment: No, I didn't check **GD** enabled for the CLI version of PHP. I only checked in the php.ini. Basically composer update/install is done by the **CircleCI**. How can I check **GD** enabled for the CLI version of PHP?

Comment: I don't know which exact version you are using, but Google provides some different ways of doing that. Otherwise, you could check whether that CI really needs an enabled version of GD - are you running tests that rely on a fully working environment? If not, simply skip the check for extensions through `--ignore-platform-reqs`

Comment: Mentioned extention is requrired as per maatwebsite/excel documentation. Version details: 
PHP - 7.3
maatwebsite/excel - 3.1
Laravel: 5.6

Comment: If that extension is required, then please enable it. If you need help with that, please share your attempts

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/220476/discussion-between-chandan-kumar-and-nico-haase).

Comment: It's done by installing docker php gd ext on the CircleCI using yml file.